# How do I write this symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

How do I write this [ju](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FrcD.png) “ᘔ” (U+1614) in LaTeX?

Comment: What are you trying to type?  Is it Duodecimal with an upside down 2, {\textturntwo}, or is it the Canadian syllabary U+1614 "ju" (Carrier or Déné syllabics)?

Comment: You probably can find a font here. http://www.languagegeek.com/font/fontdownload.html#Dakelh

Comment: It's U+1614.
Letter of the Carrier syllabary, transcribed as ju.

Comment: I edited the title.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a font which contains the symbol, you can directly use it with lua/xelatex

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Euphemia UCAS}

\begin{document}

ᘔ 

\end{document}
```

---

To find out which font contains it, you can run `albatross ᘔ`

```
        __ __           __
.---.-.|  |  |--.---.-.|  |_.----.-----.-----.-----.
|  _  ||  |  _  |  _  ||   _|   _|  _  |__ --|__ --|
|___._||__|_____|___._||____|__| |_____|_____|_____|

                    Unicode code point [1614] mapping to ᘔ                      
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Font name                                                                   │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ .LastResort                                                                 │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Euphemia UCAS                                                               │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```